# System Volume Information\FVE2.{guid} files open prevent ejecting thumbdrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, removable-media

My Windows 10 x64 machine can't ever eject a thumbdrive.  I get a message that files are open.  I ran nirsoft OpenFilesView and it shows me the following drives are open:

```
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{24e6f0ae-6a00-4f73-984b-75ce9942852d}
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{aff97bac-a69b-45da-aba1-2cfbce434750}.1
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{aff97bac-a69b-45da-aba1-2cfbce434750}.2
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{e40ad34d-dae9-4bc7-95bd-b16218c10f72}.1
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{e40ad34d-dae9-4bc7-95bd-b16218c10f72}.2
E:\System Volume Information\FVE2.{e40ad34d-dae9-4bc7-95bd-b16218c10f72}.3
```

The file in question is protected with Bitlocker, but it happens on all my removable USB drives.

I've seen some articles on earlier Windows versions saying that you could flag drives as being for "quick removal" but I don't see that option I Windows 10.

Comment: the option is still in device manager like it was in earlier windows versions